# Change layout Margin from within a thread on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a game running in a thread, and I want to modify the margins of a view from within the thread.

The following code works fine for changing the Margins of the view from the main Activity, but I need to change them from within the thread after an AlertDialog is closed.

```
View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.viewname);
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) View.getLayoutParams();
mlp.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
```

BUT, in the thread, the same code just returns null pointer exceptions.

I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Put a function in your Activity to modify the margins. Then call it from your Thread. You can see an example using Handler and Runnable [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#threading)

Comment: I put the function in my main activity, but the thread is run from a separate view that is crated in the main activity, and I can't seem to reference it.

Comment: Do you mean that the Thread is created in a separate Activity? Can you post more of your code, maybe in a gist (https://gist.github.com/) if it is really long?